# How to Unit Test a Lambda Implemented with AWS SDK for Go V2

Tags: unit-testing, go, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Given the following simple lambda written in Go that just returns a table description...

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb"
    "go.uber.org/zap"
)

var (
    dynamoDBTableName = aws.String(os.Getenv(EnvDynamoDBTableName))

    logger = func() *zap.Logger {
        l, err := zap.NewProduction()
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("failed to create zap logger: %v", err)
        }
        return l
    }()
)

func handler(ctx context.Context, req events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) 
    (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {

    defer logger.Sync()

    resp := events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{}

    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error("failed to load AWS config", zap.Error(err))
        return resp, fmt.Errorf("failed to load AWS config: %w", err)
    }

    svc := dynamodb.NewFromConfig(cfg)

    // fake logic
    t, err := svc.DescribeTable(ctx, &dynamodb.DescribeTableInput{TableName: dynamoDBTableName})
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error("failed to describe table", zap.String("table-name", *dynamoDBTableName), zap.Error(err))
    }
    var sb strings.Builder
    enc := json.NewEncoder(&sb)
    err = enc.Encode(t.Table)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error("failed to JSON encode response", zap.Error(err))
    }
    resp.Body = sb.String()
    resp.StatusCode = http.StatusOK

    return resp, nil
}

func main() {
   lambda.Start(handler)
}
```

... how do I unit test it locally? With the old SDK it was possible to use dependency injection like this:

```
type deps struct 
    svc dynamodbiface.DynamoDBAPI
    table string
}

func (d *deps) handler(ctx context.Context, req events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) 
    (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    
    ...
}

func main() {
   s := session.Must(session.NewSession())
   d := deps {
       svc: dynamodb.New(s),
       table: dynamoDBTableName,
   }

   lambda.Start(d.handler)
}
```

How do I test a lambda written with the new AWS SDK for Go V2 given that I need the context to load the config required by `dynamodb.NewFromConfig`?

Comment: I think you can simply start a new context in your unit tests, try using `context.TODO()`. You can then set some credentials only intended for testing purposes using ENV vars and the sdk will resolve them correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make your handler a humble object, so we can "skip" testing it:

```golang
func handler(ctx context.Context, req events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) 
    (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    dynamoWrapper := &RealDynamoWrapper{}
    proxyController := &ProxyController{DynamoWrapper: dynamoWrapper}
    return proxyController.proxy(ctx, req)
```

The idea is to make the handler function humble by making it delegate all the complexity to the `proxyController`.

Now, lets consider the `ProxyController` to be under test, we need to define it first:

```golang
type ProxyController struct {
  dynamoWrapper DynamoWrapper
}

func(controller *ProxyController) Proxy(ctx context.Context, req events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
  // this is where your implementation lives that you need to mock stuff for

  // We are mocking this line from your question
  svc := controller.dynamoWrapper.NewFromConfig(...)

  // do other stuff and then return something
  return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{}, nil
}
```

You can see I'm going to depend on a wrapped version of dynamo, which looks like this:

```golang
type DynamoWrapper interface {
  NewFromConfig(cfg aws.Config, optFns ...func(*Options)) *Client
}
```

Now the real implementation of this wrapper, the one referenced above as `RealDynamoWrapper` will make the call as you do to the sdk. For our test though, we want a mock implementation:

```golang
type mockDynamoWrapper struct {
  NewFromConfigFunc func(aws.Config, ...func(*Options)) *Client
}

func(dynamoWrapper *mockDynamoWrapper) NewFromConfig(cfg aws.Config, optFns ...func(*Options)) *Client {
  return dynamoWrapper.NewFromConfigFunc(cfg, optFns...)
}
```

Lastly in your test you can now mock the dynamo call:

```golang
func TestProxyController(t *testing.T) {
  // given
  dynamoWrapper := &mockDynamoWrapper{}
  proxyController := &ProxyController{DynamoWrapper: mockDynamoWrapper}
  request := events.APIGatewayProxyRequest{}
  dynamoWrapper.NewFromConfigFunc = func(aws.Config, ...func(*Options)) *Client {
    // setup your mock function to do whatever you want
  }

  // when
  proxyController.proxy(context.Background, request)

  // then do your asserts
}
```